# Android: Class not found exception

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I've looked all similar questions and none of the solutions presented did solve my problem.

When my application is launcher I am presented with the following:

```
12-23 19:27:39.207: E/Trace(1884): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-23 19:27:39.217: D/AndroidRuntime(1884): Shutting down VM
12-23 19:27:39.217: W/dalvikvm(1884): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416ae300)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.triandria.socialgeek.SocialGeek: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.triandria.socialgeek.SocialGeek
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4124)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.triandria.socialgeek.SocialGeek
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
12-23 19:27:39.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1884):     ... 11 more
```

My class that extends Application

```
public class SocialGeek extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "Social Geek";
    private static Context context;
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static SQLiteDatabase savedProfilesDatabase;
    private static DatabaseHelper savedProfilesDatabaseHelper;
    private static int width, height;
    private static boolean REMOTE_PROFILE_CREATED = false;
    private static Location CURRENT_USER_LOCATION;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SocialGeek.context = getApplicationContext();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Activity_my_profile.FILENAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        calculateScreenDimensions();
        //TODO if no memory card is present we get errors
        savedProfilesDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(
                SavedProfilesDatabaseScheme.SavedProfilesTable.PROFILE_NAME,
                "Dobrovnik");
        contentValues
                .put(SavedProfilesDatabaseScheme.SavedProfilesTable.PROFILE_DESCRIPTION,
                        " Stolischnaya University");
        savedProfilesDatabase = savedProfilesDatabaseHelper
                .getWritableDatabase();// only for mock data

        // int rowsDeleted =
        // savedProfilesDatabase.delete(SavedProfilesTable.TABLE_NAME, null,
        // null);// duplicate values? mock
        // Log.d(TAG, "Rows deleted: "+rowsDeleted);
        Long newRowId = savedProfilesDatabase.insert(
                SavedProfilesTable.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.d(TAG, ("Inserted row: " + newRowId.toString()));
        savedProfilesDatabase.close();
    }
`
```

UPDATE: Seems like the problem is not in the libraries or any particular class, even if I remove the `SocialGeek extends Application` I got the same exception in my `MainActivity`. I removed all my dependencies, deleted even eclipse and re-installed but the problem remains...

Comment: What class name did you add to `<application>` tag in manifest file ?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this issue? It may be difficult for others to provide assistance without knowing what options you have already explored.

Comment: The class name I had was `.SocialGeek`, I then changed it to `com.triandria.socialgeek.SocialGeek` @Willis I tried lot's of things such as changing the manifest's class name, remove the code that runs on the onCreate() method of the SocialGeek class, cleaning my project, removing any libraries etc.

Comment: `SocialGeek.context = getApplicationContext();` is unneeded,  you can always get the application context from any context in your app. in cases like `new DatabaseHelper(context)` where you are in the application class you can just use `new DatabaseHelper(this)`

Comment: Changing a class name or a file or anything usually requires that the project be refactored. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Willis Aren't eclipse and the Android-tools already taking care of that? I did Project-> Clean Up several times. Do you perhaps mean something else?

Comment: Here are a few things to try. 1. Synchronize and rebuild the project by right clicking on the project and selecting "Synchronize", then rebuild. 2. Close and restart Android Studio. 3. Clear system cache by navigating to "File" --> "Invalidate Caches / Restart".

Comment: Tried everything. I even exluded the file that causes the problem from the build path and the manifest. The problem replicated but now it goes on saying that my main activity class is not found. I suspect that will happen with any of my activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out.

I had to right click the `project -> build path-> configure build path -> Source` tab

and **un-tick** the `Allow output folders for source folders`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `package com.triandria.socialgeek;` on the first line in java file?

Comment: Yes I do. i just did not copy that line.